# Select mulitple columns in Laravel Request

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Im currently working on a Scoreboard, and I would like to show all users and their scores in the Scoreboard

```
public function getNames(Request $request) {

$usernames = Highscore::orderBy('score', 'DESC')->get('username');
return response()->json($usernames);
```

With this request I get every User existing in the Database, but when i try....

```
get('username', 'score');
```

... I still only get the usernames. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the columns you want to select in an array. The query builder takes an array of columns to select in the get() method

```
$usernames = Highscore::orderBy('score', 'DESC')->get(['username', 'score]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if use Laravel 5.2 using Eloquent

```
get(['score', 'username'])
```